# STM32H735VGT6 "target not found" after upload own code

Tags: stm32, software-design, stm32cubeide, st-link

I have a hard problem with a STM32. After uploading my own code to the STM32 it is not posibble to reconnect with them.

The error feedback: *17:18:34 : Error: No STM32 target found! If your product embeds Debug Authentication, please perform a discovery using Debug Authentication*

I'm  working with the **STM32H735VGT6**, connected with **ST-link V2**, software **STM32CUBEIDE **and **STM32CubeProgrammer**.

What can cause this problem?
How do I reconnect to the STM32?

I have tried:

1. Make BOOT0 HIGH, without results.
2. I have removed several STM32 from the PCB again and placed a new one, after which it works. After my software has been uploaded, things go wrong and the STM32 can no longer be reached.

Option that I will try with new STM32:

- Uploading blinking software.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have reprogrammed the SWD pins and they are not available for debugging (PA13 & PA14). You need to ***connect under reset** in STM cube programming or STMCubeIDE. Sometimes it is needed to keep NRST line manually low when the probe connects to ther uC.

Comment: I have checked your solution, but PA13 and PA14 are configured as JTAG SWCLK (PA14) and SWDIO (PA13).